# Can add database info with MySQLI, but cannot pull Login credentials with MySQLI

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, login-script

I built a site that lets my user login/resigster their info. I had to go through and change up some of the old `mysql` to use `mysqli` reference, as I was getting errors. I can get grab users info from my Register, and insert it to the DB. However, on my Login, I cannot seem to pull the user credentials to let me in. Here's my Login Page code:

```
<?php require_once('Connections/localhost.php'); ?>
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "",     $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
$theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysqli_real_escape_string") ?    mysqli_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysqli_escape_string($theValue); /* $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue); */

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}

$error = "You have an issue with the connection.";

mysqli_select_db($con, 'sugabox'); /* mysql_select_db($database_localhost, $localhost);     */
$query_Login = "SELECT * FROM users";
$Login = mysqli_query($con, $query_Login) or die(mysqli_error($error));
$row_Login = $Login->fetch_assoc(); /* $row_Login = mysql_fetch_assoc($Login); */
$totalRows_Login = $Login->num_rows; /* $totalRows_Login = mysql_num_rows($Login); */
?>

<?php
// *** Validate request to login to this site.
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
}

$loginFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_GET['accesscheck'])) {
  $_SESSION['PrevUrl'] = $_GET['accesscheck'];
}

if (isset($_POST['Username'])) {
  $loginUsername=$_POST['Username'];
  $password=$_POST['Password'];
  $MM_fldUserAuthorization = "UserLevel";
  $MM_redirectLoginSuccess = "Account.php";
  $MM_redirectLoginFailed = "Login.php";
  $MM_redirecttoReferrer = true;
  mysqli_select_db($con, 'sugabox'); /* mysql_select_db($database_localhost, $localhost); */

  $LoginRS__query=sprintf("SELECT Username, Password, UserLevel FROM users WHERE     Username=%s AND Password=%s",
  GetSQLValueString($loginUsername,"text"), GetSQLValueString($password,"text")); 

  $LoginRS = mysqli_query($con, $LoginRS__query) or die(mysqli_error($error)); /*     $LoginRS = mysql_query($LoginRS__query, $localhost) or die(mysql_error()); */
  $loginFoundUser = $LoginRS->num_rows; /* $loginFoundUser = mysql_num_rows($LoginRS); */
  if ($loginFoundUser) {

    $loginStrGroup  = mysql_result($LoginRS,0,'UserLevel');

    if (PHP_VERSION >= 5.1) {session_regenerate_id(true);} else     {session_regenerate_id();}
    //declare two session variables and assign them
    $_SESSION['MM_Username'] = $loginUsername;
    $_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'] = $loginStrGroup;       

    if (isset($_SESSION['PrevUrl']) && true) {
      $MM_redirectLoginSuccess = $_SESSION['PrevUrl'];  
    } 
    header("Location: " . $MM_redirectLoginSuccess );
  }
  else {
    header("Location: ". $MM_redirectLoginFailed );
  }
}
?>

//Form Starts Here...

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Login</title>
<link href="CSS/Layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="CSS/Menu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<style type="text/css">
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
font-weight: bold;
}
</style>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>

<body>
<div id="Holder">
<div id="Header"></div>
<div id="NavBar">
    <nav>
      <ul>
            <li><a href="Login.php">Login</a></li>
            <li><a href="Register.php">Register</a></li>
            <li><a href="ForgotPassword.php">Forget Password</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
<div id="Content">
    <div id="PageHeading">
      <h1>Log In!</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="ContentLeft">
      <h2>Insert a Message Here</h2>
      <h6><br />
    Your Message</h6>
    </div>
  <div id="ContentRight">
    <form ACTION="<?php echo $loginFormAction; ?>" id="LoginForm" name="LoginForm" method="POST">
      <table width="400" border="0" align="center">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td><label>Username:<br>
            </label>
              <input name="Username" type="text" class="StyleTxtField" id="Username"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><label>Password:<br>
            </label>
              <input name="Password" type="password" class="StyleTxtField"     id="Password"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" name="LoginButton" id="LoginButton" value="Login">    </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="Footer"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
<?php
mysqli_free_result($Login);
?>
```

The places where you see comments are where I changed the old code to be able to accommodate `mysqli`... apperantly, something isn't right somewhere, but I don't know where. Can any provicde assistance, so that my login works? I've many other things, but can't seem to figure out where I'm going wrong here.

Comment: please read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: HOW is this not working for you? You get php errors? mysql errors? Regardless of that, you're vastly overcomplicating the whole business. getsqlvaluestring() is pointless. You're using MySQLi. Use prepared statements and placeholders.

Comment: No more errors, I weeded them all out with using sqli... The errors said to use either sqli or PDO.

Comment: You will still be getting errors. Your calls to `mysqli_real_escape_string()` will fail because you haven't included a connection parameter. `mysqli_*()` is __not the same__ as `mysql_*()`. Check the required syntax in the manual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are redirecting the user to another page you need to use

```
session_start();
```

at the top of the script.

Comment: This was most helpful, yet I re-did the code entirely using PDO as instructed. Yet I have an issue with one small issue, and will post. Thanks.

Comment: you are welcome, glad I could help. Let me know if you need any more help ;). Also, small suggestion for your future posts, put your code pieces by pieces so its easier to read for those who want to help. When its hard to read people usually just dont feel like helping. cheers